# Shopify: Is there way to update products with SKU?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I have around 10k products imported to Shopify, and I'm adding products through API regularly.

I'm not able to find the API (REST or GRAPH) to update the product using the SKU.

When I add the product through API I get the product_id in response so I'm able to update the product later using it. But If I'm able to update the product with SKU then I will not have to maintain product ids of Shopify. So is there any API to update the product with SKU? I couldn't find it in docs...

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any Shopify API to update Product by SKU. If you look at [Product](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product) and [Product Variant](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/product-variant) properties, you will see that SKU is the property of Product Variant rather than Product as stated in your question.

To seamlessly integrate this into your existing system where you want to update Products based on SKU value, keep a mapping of SKU to Product Id. This mapping can be in a form of CSV, JSON or some database. Given the SKU values as input, map them to their Shopify product Ids and send update request.

Or use some third party app like [Excelify](https://excelify.io/tutorials/update-shopify-product-by-sku/#:%7E:text=Update%20Product%20Handle%20or%20Title,it%20would%20be%20by%20default.) that also does the same thing under the hood.